# Coming from KScope, then how to use serach in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, search

I installed Eclipse (Galileo) and CDT on my Linux platfrom to replace KScope. I imported my project by creating a clean Makefile Project.

In KScope, I could right-click on a variable, function, whatever and quickly search for references, etc. If I do the same in Eclipse, it does not work, except if I do a Search Text. But then, Eclipse does a linear File Search, which is very slow and which misses for some reasons (because of #ifdef's ?) the correct line numbers.

Can somebody advice me how to
- how to update the index database of a C-Project, or
- how to speed up the search?

Or is there a Plugin that provides same or similar functionalities as in KScope?

Thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `F3` or click on the variable/etc. with the left mouse button while you press `Ctrl`.

[EDIT] [stefangachter][1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216831/stefangachter) found something else:

> I figured out that Eclipse switches off the live parsing for huge files (see Window | Preferences | C/C++ | Editor | Scalability). Therefore, the live parsing did not work for certain files. So, if you have problems with live parsing, then check the scalability options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, when I do that, I get the message 'Could not find symbol in index'. So, how can I update the index accordingly?

Comment: It should do that automatically. Are you using the latest version of CDT? Can Eclipse build the project without errors?

Comment: Yes, it compiles the Makefile project without any errors. Actually, I recreated the project and the indexer run anew. Now, for certain functions, the F3 works, but for others not. I don't understand yet, why certain functions are out of scope.

Comment: Odd. Add a space to a file which contains a missing function, then save. That should trigger the index. Check that F3 works inside the file. Then try it in a different file.

Comment: I figured out that Eclipse switches off the live parsing for huge files (see Window | Preferences | C/C++ | Editor | Scalability). Therefore, the live parsing did not work for certain files. So, if you have problems with live parsing, then check the scalability options.